# Mixed Content warning when viewing public careers profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, ssl

When viewing my public careers profile or open the profile in careers for editing I get a mixed content warning in Chrome for the favicon.ico. The warning does not occur when browsing careers.

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jehof' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Looks like a relative reference to stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico is being redirected to an HTTP URI. Investigating *why* now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Root cause of this is because //stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico redirects to our CDN. However, it doesn't respect the scheme used in the original request.

We're looking into why that's happening but for now I've pushed a fix that just changes references to //stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico to the CDN URI directly.